# Java: what does the following expression mean?

Tags: java, expression

What does the following expression mean? Can someone please tell me?

```
!((number > 6)  ||  (number  <=  2))
```

Comment: Consider rewriting expressions into forms that are easier to understand: `!((number > 6)  ||  (number  <=  2))` (by DeMorgan's) -> `!(number > 6) && !(number <= 2)` (because integers are closed) -> `(number <= 6) && (number > 2)` (order for clarity) -> `number > 2 && number <= 6`

Comment: Why do you down vote the guy? Maybe he is new to programming that is just mean!

Comment: @Whitecat I didn't down-vote, but the *way* questions are asked generally plays a big role in the [initial storm of] down-votes. i.e. usually trying something or showing some reasoning (even if incorrect) will yield in a better response.

Comment: @Whitecat too bad this question should have been answered by consulting a manual / tutorial (didn't downvote).

Comment: `!((number > 6)  ||  (number  <=  2))`

Let's split this up:

* `(number > 6)` - `number` is greater than six. This one should be obvious
* `(number <= 2)` - `number` is less than or equal to two. 
* `((number > 6)  ||  (number  <=  2))` - `||` means "or": Number is greater than six or it is less than or equal to two.
* `!((number > 6)  ||  (number  <=  2))` - `!` means "not": It is not the case that either the Number is greater than six or it is less than or equal to two.

Comment: @Whitecat: Before you start flinging around accusations, I didn't downvote - although it *is* a bad question, and I can entirely understand why some people *did* downvote.

Comment: @commenters I did not mean to accuse the commenters of downvoting. I just meant that statement in general. But the "What part don't you understand" is condescending. 
I agree that the question is bad but let him know that he should put the parts he doesn't understand in the question.

Comment: @Whitecat: I *did* downvote because 'this question does not show any research effort...'. It would have been easy to find some good tutorials about boolean expressions in general and Java in special. Second, the question does not even provide context (the if statement).

Comment: @Whitecat: No, it's not condescending - it's trying to get the OP to think about it and show us which part is confusing. The OP has already had advice about how to ask a good question, when they agreed to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice, of course. They seem not to have understood it fully, hence digging for more information. If the OP had edited their question to explain which part was causing the confusion, we could have helped them. But no...

Comment: @Whitecat: And the OP has been around for 31 days, and asked 16 questions. This is a *bad* question, and I see no problem with downvoting it for that reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It checks to see whether `number` is between 2 and 6. More specifically, it checks to see if `number` is one of these:

```
3
4
5
6
```

A better way of writing it would be: `(number > 2 && number <= 6)`

Comment: I don't get it. Mine says number<=2 so how come you changed it to number>2? It different, no? Mine says if number is smaller or equal to and your says if number is bigger.

Comment: @EliUnger See the comment made by pst to your question: !((number > 6)  ||  (number  <=  2)) is the same as !(number > 6) && !(number <= 2), which is the same as (number <= 6) && (number > 2). You don't have number <= 2, but !(number <= 2)